# google sheet : insert blank column in query output

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to extract some column from master table/sheet. I can use query() or filter() or vlookup() but for this example, i use this very simple formula in cell A100 :

```
={ calc_01!C15:C ,calc_01!F15:F }
```

It works fine and it will just output 2 columns in A and B column (start from row 100).

The problem is : how if i want the output into 3 column (A,B,C) where the 2nd column or column B will be empty. So i tried something like this , trying to make the 2nd column blank :

```
={ calc_01!C15:C ,"",calc_01!F15:F }
```

If i put it on cell A100, i expect the output will occupy column A,B and C (where B is blank). But it doesn't work. So does anyone know if possible to do it ?

Why i want to do this? because i have condition where on the top i have some kind of table formatting where the B column is too narrow and i'm not allowed to adjust its width, so i have to use column c instead of B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=index({ 'calc_01'!C15:C ,if(row('calc_01'!C15:C),,),'calc_01'!F15:F })
```

and see if that works?